# How to get the chron time column back?

Tags: r

I used to have a chron time column in my data, but chron time changed into characters when I was doing some transforms from list to data frame. I want to get the chron time column back, how to do that?

now the chron time column looks like below, and the attribute is character. I want to change it back to chron. I used the function as.chron(), but it doesn't work.

```
[1] "18408.5534143519" "18408.5697800926" "18408.6092824074" "18408.6126273148"
[5] "18408.6261921296" "18408.6345023148" "18408.677962963"  "18408.6815277778"
[9] "18409.3885416667" "18409.3949652778" "18409.4003125"    "18409.438900463" 
[13] "18409.4422222222" "18409.4495023148" "18409.4690856481" "18409.4788310185"
```

Comment: While there is code that will reconstitute (likely `as.chron` and `as.numeric`), but I think a better approach is to re-import the data and fix the processing that is causing this mistake. Conversion from number-like to string and back to number-like can be a lossy conversion.

Comment: If the resolution is seconds there is more than enough digits.

Comment: Please note the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and, in particular, that the output of `dput(x)` where x is your input should be shown in the problem so that it is easily reproducible by others.  I have done it for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
library(chron)
as.chron(as.numeric(x))
```

giving:

```
 [1] (05/26/20 13:16:55) (05/26/20 13:40:29) (05/26/20 14:37:22)
 [4] (05/26/20 14:42:11) (05/26/20 15:01:43) (05/26/20 15:13:41)
 [7] (05/26/20 16:16:16) (05/26/20 16:21:24) (05/27/20 09:19:30)
[10] (05/27/20 09:28:45) (05/27/20 09:36:27) (05/27/20 10:32:01)
[13] (05/27/20 10:36:48) (05/27/20 10:47:17) (05/27/20 11:15:29)
[16] (05/27/20 11:29:31)
```

### Note

```
x <- c("18408.5534143519", "18408.5697800926", "18408.6092824074", 
"18408.6126273148", "18408.6261921296", "18408.6345023148", "18408.677962963", 
"18408.6815277778", "18409.3885416667", "18409.3949652778", "18409.4003125", 
"18409.438900463", "18409.4422222222", "18409.4495023148", "18409.4690856481", 
"18409.4788310185")
```